# Problems running xampp

Tags: windows-8, iis, localhost, xampp, avast

I was having trouble with xampp.

I uninstalled it and since I've tried reinstalling it, cannot get it to work.

My first error was that port 80 was being used. As [addressed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788348/how-do-i-free-my-port-80-on-localhost-windows).

Now it is telling me there are no modules installed.

I keep getting a warning about having antivirus software running, I use Avast and I can say I have had trouble with it running executables in Visual Studio. I have gone through and changed as many settings as I can instructing Avast not to scan my files, downloads, etc.

I have also stopped avast from running altogether for the install and run.

I've tried changing ports.

It's driving me nuts. I just can't get it working and it's been 2 days now.

I use windows 8 on a 64 bit os.

When I type `http://localhost:80/`  into the address bar it takes me to `microsoft.com/web` I uninstalled the software associated with the microsoft server and it, has made no difference.

I can provide more information, as required.

I can provide more details that may assist. If anyone can help. Thanks.

---

**edit**

I also followed a comprehensive 4 page guide to manually install it, provided by my Uni.

Comment: I think there's other questions on the former part - it interfers with the html services needed for some applications running under modern/metro/windows store UI. Also, XAMPP is.. rather legendarily crap. You might be better off running a proper lamp stack in a VM. Not really the answer you want, but something worth thinking seriously about.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek oh yes yes yes I agree I detest xampp, what do you recommend to test my website for php (it's for uni and they are shoving xampp down our throats).. I have even contemplated just uploading my files to my hosted website to ttest them there.. that's how frustrated I am

Comment: I'd just do a simple debian based VM if possible. xampp and windows 8 simply do NOT get along.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek pls turn your comments into an answer... as I agree with you and think it is a valid answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 and xampp simply do not get along  A good chunk of what you would find searching for [xampp windows 8](https://superuser.com/search?q=xampp%20windows%208) would show this. Since many metro/modernui/windows store apps are HTML based, windows 8 apparently runs a stripped down webserver.

That aside, xampp, while 'simple' uses a less secure setup tailors for ease of use, you're better off simply getting a VM host software and setting up a LAMP stack on it

Comment: I need a couple of upvotes on my posts here to upvote u guys. I used all my rep on a bounty

Comment: thnx, I have installed oracle VM

Comment: Set XAMPP to use a different port, like 81 instead of 80! (And I can't believe that they - MS - use port 80 for this!)

Comment: They seem to. I guess no one ever, runs a web server on a desktop ;p

Answer (score 1):

- Look in the hosts file: `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\`. Make a backup of the file first! If you see microsoft.com somewhere, delete that line. (I can't imagine that the problem is this, but you can check anyway.)
- Open Services, and try to find a webservice there. Stop it and check again.
- Try netstat, and see what service is running on port 80.